# Take big lists and form a table to export or copy to manipulate in excel

Tags: python-2.7

Here is the code so far items_list, new_hit_counter, and new_potential_htc are all lists of the same length and very long.

```
p = 0

while p < len(items_list):

    dfresult = pd.DataFrame(data={"Item":[items_list[p]], "Total Supplier":[new_total_parts[p]], "Total Hit Counter":[new_hit_counter[p]], "Potential Hit Counter":[new_potential_htc[p]], "Frequency Used":(new_hit_counter[p]/new_potential_htc[p])})       
    dfresult = dfresult[['Item', 'Total Supplied', 'Total Hit Counter', 'Potential Hit Counter', 'Frequency Used']]
    print dfresult
    print("")    
    p = p + 1
```

Giving me an output like:

```
          Item  Total Supplied  Total Hit Counter  Potential Hit Counter  Frequency Used
  0 025-07-124               4                  2                      7        0.285714

          Item  Total Supplied  Total Hit Counter  Potential Hit Counter  Frequency Used
  0  03-824-08               0                  0                      7               0

          Item  Total Supplied  Total Hit Counter  Potential Hit Counter  Frequency Used
  0  1017895              10                  5                      7        0.714286
```

I am iterating on each element and creating one row of data each time.
I would like the data to be all together. Where the titles will stay at the top and then all data would come underneath it. So the index would be going up 0,1,2,3....
Any ideas are much appreciated.